# ShObjIdl location for JNA usage

Tags: java, windows, dll, jna, wallpaper

I'm trying to use shobjidl_core.h library to run code that changes the wallpaper of one specific monitor, specifically I need to run these two functions: [GetMonitorDevicePathAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-getmonitordevicepathat), [SetWallpaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-setwallpaper).

Now, when I run the following code:

```java
    interface shobjidl_core extends Library {
        test.shobjidl_core INSTANCE = Native.load( "shobjidl_core", shobjidl_core.class);

        void GetMonitorDevicePathAt(int monitorIndex, WString m);
        void SetWallpaper(WString monitorId, WString wallpaperPath);
    }
```

I get an error saying `"Unable to load library 'shobjidl'"`

I've tried any variation of "shobjidl" but still I can't find one that works. From what I understood about JNA it need a dll containing the library, but I can't find any dll related to shobjidl

What should I do to load shobjidl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped on the JNA google group. The answer that solved my issue can be seen [here](https://groups.google.com/g/jna-users/c/6yz2VPwC4w4). If you want to see a use case example on how to do this you can check it on [github](https://github.com/matthiasblaesing/JNA-Demos/tree/master/IDesktopWallpaper)

Answer (score 1):

shobjidl is a C/C++ header file, it is not a library shipped with Windows. The functions declared in those headers often end up in shell32.dll or shcore.dll but in this case you are actually talking about `IDesktopWallpaper` and this is a COM object.

Use JNA or JNI or whatever method of COM interaction you prefer.

A minimal C++ example can be found [here](https://github.com/mvaneerde/blog/tree/develop/desktopwallpaper).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it set me on the right track